# How do I debug within my WebStorm workspace?

Tags: debugging, gruntjs, webstorm

I start my application on `localhost:9000` using a `grunt serve` command. The application is using yeoman. All my node modules and bower components are in place. I am trying to use the inbuilt grunt task runner - right click and debug serve command. However, it starts the debugger in some other port.

I also tried creating run/debug configurations but that does not seem to have a Grunt debug option.

I am using WebStorm 11.0.3. Any pointers to do this?

Comment: Simple, don't use `grunt serve` when you're debugging.  Configure webstorm to launch your application when you need to use its debugging tools, and reference the port that it uses.

Comment: It uses a different port eveytime. Basically it should be using 9000 correct?

Comment: My app opens up a browser window automatically when I RUN it. But the debug does not do that and I do not see it stopping at the breakpoints either.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to debug? Server-side code or client-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug client-side code of your app create a new JavaScript run/debug configuration. In the URL field specify localhost:9000. Click save, put the breakpoints in your client-side code and hit debug.